# Need unicode characters in UITableView from SQLite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, unicode, nsstring, uilabel

I have some NSString varibales that incude items like
Ð and Õ and if I do

```
cell.textLabel.text = person.name;
```

and if it contains one of those characters the cell.textlabel is blank!

I have discovered that if I use

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

To pull my data back it pulls back null, however using the deprectared method

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

Shows the characters!

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like sqlite3_column_text is using MacRoman encoding.  Can you dump the contents in hex and see if it looks like UTF8 (Ð == \xC3\x90, Õ == \xC3\x95) or MacRoman.

Comment: How do I dump the hex?  I can control the column format in my sqlite so what should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually played around and got the answer!

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Iirc, char is a cstring, in the first sql ex you're putting UTF8 multibyte characters into single byte c string so that will be bad, null, or unpredictable.

As for putting UTF8 into a label, it can def be done since there are Asian language apps.  Maybe there's a tutorial for that you can look up.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, I know the stuff you are saying but why does the CString work and the UTF8 not?  Ignore the label, when I NSLog() the col1 variable it returns (null) if those characters are anywhere in the string.